# Unity how to make dropdown automatically select an option when scrolling?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dropdown

I am trying to get unity's dropdown automatically select (currently say the centre) option when scrolling. Then by applying elasticity, it may cover the full range of items.

As far as I know, it may be done by registering an event that get the current area of the visible panel and then looks for the item that covers the center of the visible panel.

I don't know how to get the area of the visible panel, nor do I know the way to get the item according to its location in the panel.
Can anyone please give some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Set the default value of the dropdown by setting the Value property to the index of option you want in the DropDown UI component.

Answer (score 0):

```
dropdown.value = dropdown.options.FindIndex(option => option.text == "an Option");
```

Use dropdown.value to set its default index, or if you know the default option string, you can set the value by looking for the index from options with that string.